# getting error in tuple working on a project of deep survillieance and getting an error

Tags: python

--------Stuck on tuple part in the section training_data its again and again showing out of range whats the problem this project is on deep survillience python version 3.7 windows 10------------------

```
store_image=[]
train_path='C:\\Users\\lenovo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\train'
fps=5
train_videos=os.listdir(train_path)
train_images_path=train_path+'/frames'
os.makedirs(train_images_path)
def store_inarray(image_path):
    image=load_img(image_path)
    image=img_to_array(image)
    image=cv2.resize(image, (227,227), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray=0.2989*image[:,:,0]+0.5870*image[:,:,1]+0.1140*image[:,:,2]
    store_image.append(gray)

def store_inarray(image_path):
    image=load_img(image_path)
    image=img_to_array(image)
    image=cv2.resize(image, (227,227), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray=0.2989*image[:,:,0]+0.5870*image[:,:,1]+0.1140*image[:,:,2]
    store_image.append(gray)

# for video in train_videos:
#         os.system( 'ffmpeg -i {}/{} -r 1/{}  {}/frames/%03d.jpg'.format(train_path,video,fps,train_path))
#         images=os.listdir(train_images_path)
#         for image in images:
#             image_path=framepath+ '/'+ image
#           store_inarray(image_path)
for video in train_videos:
    os.system( 'ffmpeg -i {}/{} -r 1/{}  {}/frames/%03d.jpg'.format(train_path,video,fps,train_path))
    images=os.listdir(train_images_path)
    for image in images:
        # image_path=train_image_path + '/' + image
        image_path=train_images_path+'/'+image
        store_inarray(image_path)
        store_image=np.array(store_image)
        
        a,b,c=store_image.shape
        store_image.resize(b,c,a)
        store_image=(store_image-store_image.mean())/(store_image.std())
        store_image=np.clip(0,1,store_image)
    np.save('training.npy',store_image)


#define stae_model

stae_model=Sequential()
stae_model.add(Conv3D(filters=128,kernel_size=(11,11,1),strides=(4,4,1),padding='valid',input_shape=(227,227,10,1),activation='tanh'))
stae_model.add(Conv3D(filters=64,kernel_size=(5,5,1),strides=(2,2,1),padding='valid',activation='tanh'))
stae_model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=1,padding='same',dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.3,return_sequences=True))
stae_model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=1,padding='same',dropout=0.3,return_sequences=True))
stae_model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=1,return_sequences=True, padding='same',dropout=0.5))
stae_model.add(Conv3DTranspose(filters=128,kernel_size=(5,5,1),strides=(2,2,1),padding='valid',activation='tanh'))
stae_model.add(Conv3DTranspose(filters=1,kernel_size=(11,11,1),strides=(4,4,1),padding='valid',activation='tanh'))

stae_model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])


training_data=np.load('training.npy')
frames=training_data.shape[2]
frames=frames-frames%10
training_data=training_data[:,:,:frames]
training_data=training_data.reshape(-1,227,227,10)
training_data=np.expand_dims(training_data,axis=4)
target_data=training_data.copy()
epochs=5
batch_size=1
```

----------------------------error----------------
frames=training_data.shape[2]
IndexError:tuple index out of range

Comment: please provide the entire error message beginning with "Taceback" in your question

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/lenovo/OneDrive/Desktop/train/train.py", line 68, in <module>
    frames=training_data.shape[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range